# Is it safe to use new JDK APIs in test code, if production code is targeting older JRE?

Tags: java, backwards-compatibility

I'm building a Maven module using the latest JDK but targeting JRE 8.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <release>8</release>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Since unit tests are not contained in the resulting jar file, I assume that I can use APIs from newer JDKs such as the collection factory methods from [JEP 269](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/269).

Can I do this or should I expect any problems?

---

**Bonus question**: Can I even use new *language* features such as the `var` type name from [JEP 286](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/286)? If so, what would be necessary to convince Maven to compile test code with a different source version than production code?

Answer (score 3):

I had always assumed that compiling with "-target/-source" would ensure that my classes were 100% compatible with the target Java release.

I was mistaken.

In my case:

1. I was using Ant/build.xml or Eclipse, and Java 1.7...
2. ... to build .jars and .wars intended to run under WebSphere app servers running Java 1.5 or 1.6.
3. Even though the *class files* had a version stamp matching the target...
4. ... the .jar/.war might sometimes bring in unwanted *dependencies* against the newer Java version.
5. My solution:

   a) I kept a copy of the "old JDK" (including the "old" tools.jar, for Ant builds)

   b) I wrote a .bat file to do the build using the old JDK (I needed a .bat file because Eclipse/Ant refused to run against the older Java)

To answer your question:

- It *should* work...
- ... but test the heck out of it.
- If you want to "play it safe" - then do your actual build using the target version (as I did).

Answer (score 0):

You generally want to keep your test environment as similar to the production environment as is possible (and reasonable). If the code will run on a Java 8 JRE in production then you should probably run your tests against that too, to avoid depending on newer APIs by accident.